# Importing script and calling a method on a variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular8

I'm new to typescript and I'm trying to use a bit of code I found online to change links to look nice for my site,

```
<script src="https://wow.zamimg.com/widgets/power.js"></script>
<script>var wowhead_tooltips = {
    "colorlinks": true,
    "iconizelinks": true,
    "renamelinks": true
    };
</script>
```

I included that into my index.html, and it works great, until I load a component, I spent a lot of time looking around and found that I need to call $WowheadPower.refreshLinks();

To get the links to change when a new element is added, I wasn't sure how to declare that variable in typescript so I could tie it to various angular commands I wanted to do, unless I add it in a try catch:

```
loadScript(){
    try{
        // update tooltips

        if(typeof $WowheadPower == 'undefined'){
            $.getScript('//wow.zamimg.com/widgets/power.js');
        } else {
            $WowheadPower.refreshLinks();
            console.log($WowheadPower)
        }
    } finally {}
}
```

I get an error that says 
Cannot find name '$WowheadPower'
but I saved it anyway, and somehow on my page it works as I want it too.

It works perfect, but I still got the error so I declared it

```
try{
    // update tooltips
    var $WowheadPower
    if(typeof $WowheadPower == 'undefined'){
        $.getScript('//wow.zamimg.com/widgets/power.js');
    } else {
    $   WowheadPower.refreshLinks();
        console.log($WowheadPower)
    }
} finally {}
```

and it broke, I assume because I overwrote the correctly variable that has the right method.

Now I have to leave the error in to get functionality, but the error stops me from compiling when I ng serve. Until I hit save on VScode then it works fine again.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since $WowheadPower is an external variable imported from another file, you can tell typescript that it exists without explicitly declaring it:

```
declare var $WowheadPower: any
```

write this at the beginning of your code so you tell TS that this variable exists. Ideally, you would write an interface that correctly defines `$WowheadPower`'s type instead of `any` there.